# Dismiss keyboard for UITextfield in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView to which i've assigned a UITextField to each cell. I want to be able to accept input from each text field and dismiss the keyboard when the user taps anywhere on the screen other than the keyboard. This is the code I have so far, but I find the keyboard only gets dismissed when im on the last cell in the table.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.gradesTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, (cell.contentView.bounds.size.height-30)/2, 50, 30)];

    [self.tf setDelegate: self];
    self.tf.tag = indexPath.row;

    self.tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.tf.placeholder = @"0";
    self.tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.tf.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    self.tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;

    [cell addSubview:self.tf];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.adderArrayLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGR];
    NSLog(@"Started editing");
}
```

Ive tried both `endEditing:` and `resignFirstResponder` but both only dismiss the keyboard when im on the textfield in the last cell.

```
- (void)tap {
    [self.tf endEditing:YES];
    //[self.tf resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"tap called");
    self.tapGR.enabled = NO;
}
```

With the NSLog statements in the code I can confirm the method `tap` is called every time the appropriate tap gesture is recognized but still the keyboard stays. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should add the gesture recognizer in `viewDidLoad`.  You only need to add it once--not every time a text view begins editing.

Comment: Not sure I get the question, but the tap method is called as the selector in the creation of the tap gesture recognizer, which is called when you start typing in the textfields

Comment: Right.  Which means if I try to edit 5 text fields, the gesture recognized it created 5 times when it only needs to be created once, in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
self.tf
```

Your class has a text field property, and every time you create a new text field, you assign it to this property.  Then, you only try to `endEditing:` or `resignFirstResponder` on this property, which will always be the text field on the cell most recently created.

You don't need this property at all and can just use a local text field variable when creating the cells.

Then change your tap method to this:

```
- (void)tap {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    NSLog(@"tap called");
    self.tapGR.enabled = NO;
}
```

And truly, the method should probably be: `- (void)tap:(id)sender;`

Also, as I commented, the gesture recognizer should be added in `viewDidLoad`.  We only need to add it once, not each and every time a text field begins editing.  The only reason to add it every time a text field begins editing is if you're also removing it every time the text field ends editing... but as the method that the gesture calls simply gets rid of the keyboard, I see no reason to do that.

Comment: Okay, this actually makes sense. As for the method being `- (void)tap:(id)sender;` this doesn't seem to be an option when declaring the selector in the creation of the gesture recognizer. I do remove it every time a tap is recognized because I feel calling it in `viewDidLoad` would render the rest of the screen useless as it will only be on look out for the tap. Will try anyway.

Comment: @Marcus Like this: `@selector(tap:)`